# Center text in flexbox that are subcontainer of bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, text-alignment

I was wondering if someone can help to center text on about page within body, without changing dynamic page height calculation.

here is page:
https://protasov.by/contacts/

here is jade/pug code

```
 section.container-fluid
            .row(style="padding-top:20px;").centered-form.center-block
                section.container(style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;").col-md-10.text-center
                    .wb-stl-normal(style="margin: auto; align-self: center;")
                        p
                            em TEXT
                            |  TEXT TEXT
                            br
                            span.wb-stl-small TEXT TEXT
                        br
```

I tried different approaches and can't achieve any visible result that will help me to center text in the middle of block "section.container-fluid" so that it be perfectly aligned H/V in page canvas.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added in wb_main height in precentage, set minimum.
then added d flex, and h 100 classes, and now vertical alignment works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap flex-box classes

to align horizontally use

`.d-flex .align-content-{x}` where 'x' could be `center`, `around` or `between`

to align vertically use

`.d-flex .align-items-{x}` where 'x' could be `center`, `stretch` or `baseline`

Reference to bootstrap flex-box classes [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/)

You can learn more about css flex-box [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: In the code example above it shows that the classes `align-items-center` and `justify-content-center`. It might be solved with `m-auto ` but it’s hard to tell with the incomplete code provided.

Comment: he wants to center horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Not sure, it’s really not clear. I’d guess both by that markup but I can’t be sure...

Comment: want vertical and horizontal centering in body layout

Comment: I tried to do:  
section.container-fluid
 d-flex.flex-row.justify-content-center.align-items-center
  .flex-column(style="padding-top:20px;").justify-content-stretch.wb-stl-normal.text-center
   p
    TEXT


but anyway it's sits on top of container-fluid